# Where is the segmentation fault in my code?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I keep running my code using nasm and I keep getting a segmentation fault. I assume it is because I am incorrectly exiting my code, but I have run out of ideas on how to change it. (x64 assembly)

I have tried moving around "ret" on many of my labels and moving where I call the exit syscall. I also have tried moving around my macros and I have not seen any progress.

my main file :

```
%include "utils.inc"

section .data
    ;boring begining text
    intro db "Enter 2 numbers and an operation symbol : ", 10, 0
    outro db "Your answer is : "
    number1 db "Num 1 : ", 0
    number2 db "Num 2 : ", 0
    operation db "Operation : ", 0
    error db "Invalid Operation", 0

section .bss
    num1 resb 6 ;reserve 6 characters for the first number
    num2 resb 6 ;reserve 6 charachters for the second numver
    operand resb 1 ;reserve 1 character for the operation

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    PrintString intro

    ;get the first number
    PrintString number1
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, num1
    mov rdx, 2
    syscall

    ;get the second number
    PrintString number2
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, num2
    mov rdx, 2 
    syscall

    ;get the operation
    PrintString operation
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, operand
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall

    mov al, [operand]

    ;if the operation is '*'
    cmp al, 42
    je _mult
    
    ;if the operation is '/'
    cmp al, 47
    je _div

    ;if the operation is '+'
    cmp al, 43
    je _add

    ;if the operation is '-'
    cmp al, 45
    je _sub

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
    ret

_mult:    
    ret

_div:
    ret

_add:
    ret

_sub:
    ret
```

my macros :

```
%macro Exit 0
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro PrintString 1
    mov rax, %1
    push rax
    mov rbx, 0
    %%Length:
        inc rax
        inc rbx
        mov cl, [rax]
        cmp cl, 0
        jne %%Length

        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, %1
        mov rdx, rbx
        syscall
%endmacro

%macro PrintInt 1
    section .bss
        digitSpace resb 3
        digitSpacePos resb 6

    section .text
        mov rax, %1
        mov rcx, digitSpace
        mov rbx, 10
        mov [rcx], rbx
        inc rcx
        mov [digitSpacePos], rcx

        _pushDigitsToStack:
            mov rdx, 0
            mov rbx, 10
            div rbx
            push rax
            add rdx, 48

            mov rcx, [digitSpacePos]
            mov [rcx], dl
            inc rcx
            mov [digitSpacePos], rcx
            
            pop rax
            cmp rax, 0
            jne _pushDigitsToStack


        _printDigits:
            mov rcx, [digitSpacePos]

            mov rax, 1
            mov rdi, 1
            mov rsi, rcx
            mov rdx, 1
            syscall

            mov rcx, [digitSpacePos]
            dec rcx
            mov [digitSpacePos], rcx
            
            cmp rcx, digitSpace
            jge _printDigits
%endmacro


%macro stringToInteger 1
    PLACE equ $10
    CHAR_0 equ $48 

    mov r13, CHAR_0
    mov r14, PLACE
    mov r15, %1
    push r15
    mov rax, 0
    jmp %%createInt

    %%addNum:
        sub cl, [r13]
        mul r14
        add [rax], cl
        jmp %%createInt

    %%createInt:
        inc r15
        mov cl, [r15]
        cmp cl, 0
        jne %%addNum
%endmacro
```

Comment: The debugger usually tells you exactly where the segmentation fault is. What does the debugger say?

Comment: Your `PrintString` has a `push rax` but no `pop`. Similarly in `stringToInteger` there is a `push r15`. PS: you really should not be creating such big code blocks as macros. Write proper functions.

Comment: I am not using a debugger, In the terminal after I use the commands:
nasm -f elf64 -o out.o calc.asm
ld -o run out.o
./run

the terminal responds with "zsh: segmentation fault  ./run"

Comment: Learn to use a debugger so you are at least examine a crash, but ideally single step the code.

Comment: Code jumps to labels: `_mult`,`_div`,`_add`,`_sub` and `ret` instructions pops garbage from the stack.

Comment: I added a pop rax at the end of PrintString and I am still recieving the seg fault @Jester

Comment: I thought macros were functions and the "example: ret" was a label? what are macros then used for @Jester

Comment: See also the [comment by @Nassau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77723601/where-is-the-segmentation-fault-in-my-code#comment137023361_77723601) You can not `ret` from code you did not `call`.

Comment: Solved, @Nassau was correct

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my labels, I did not need to `ret` from them since I did not call them.